# How to use limit with Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have just joined a project with Java (Hibernate I guess) and MySql in the backend. And I have this

```
    @NamedQuery(name = QSDispositivo.getAllQuestionaryBySystem2,
            query = "select q from com.pil.pos.businessobject.vm.Questionary q " +
                    "left join fetch q.system as s " +
                    "left join fetch q.reach as r " +
                    "left join fetch q.status as t " +
                    "where t.codigoSap not like ?2  " +
                    "and q.operacionId > 0 " +
                    "and s.id = ?1"),
```

but for some reason, no matter what I can not use LIMIT. I have been reading about setMax and setStart but I dont know how to use them in this, the examples are so different from this. Any help is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure of the Hibernate version that you are using, but if its Hibernate 3 then you'd have to use the setMaxResults option to limit the number of responses that you need.

```
Query.setMaxResults()
```

should do the trick for you.

Comment: I am sorry, in which line, because after the last comma a new @NamedQuery starts, and I have tried it there before.